# Question about comparative adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, comparative-constructions, comparative

The question is about filling the blank with the best answer. (with the word given in the parentheses)

> **1.** An eagle flies ........... a sparrow (high)
>
> a. Higher Than
>
> b. More Highly than
>
> **2.** Jaguars run ........... cats. (fast)
>
> a. Fast than
>
> b. Faster than

My question is about using adjective or adverb. I usually heard that the answer for **1** is a and **2** is b. But in a book I found that it answered b for **1** and a for **2**. Now what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

2 a is simply wrong. 1 b is arguably grammatically correct, but fluent speakers do not say that.

As the name implies, a comparative adjective is used when we are comparing two things. Basic adjective: Jaguars are fast. Comparative: Jaguars are faster than cats. You cannot switch them. "Jaguars are faster" does not mean the same thing as "Jaguars are fast." It is only meaningful to say "Jaguars are faster" if you are comparing them to something else. This may be in the same sentence, like "Jaguars are faster than cats", or it could be in some broader context, like, "Cats are fast. Jaguars are faster." The sentence "Jaguars are fast than cats" is just wrong: the "than cats" indicates a comparison, and so you must use the comparative form "faster".